# Async/await functionality for db.eval aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await, aggregate

I am trying to execute a db.collection.aggregate() query within a call to db.eval(). I am using eval() because I am making a dynamic number of lookups, so I generate the query by concatenating relevant strings. The query works perfectly when I manually remove the quotes from the string:

```js
await db.collection('Products').aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Golomax',
        localField: 'barcode',
        foreignField: 'barcode',
        as: 'Golomax'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$Golomax',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Masivos SA',
        localField: 'barcode',
        foreignField: 'barcode',
        as: 'Masivos SA'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$Masivos SA',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $out: 'Output'
}]).toArray();
```

Unfortunately, it does not work when I am using the string in a call to db.eval(). I put quotes around the code snippet above and set the string equal to the variable 'query' and tried this:

```js
db.eval('async function(){' + query + ' return;}', function(err, result) {
      console.log('the result is: ', result);
    });
```

I've also tried removing the word "async," and this still has not worked. How do I ensure that the function will finish aggregating before returning? Thanks.

-- EDIT --

I just noticed that db.eval() is deprecated and planned for removal. The alternative is to "implement the equivalent queries/operations using the normal MongoDB query language and client driver API." How can I do this using a string query?

Comment: What is the actual `query`?  What does it look like?  Please provide an example of it it.  `eval` is the last thing that you want to use and will no doubt lead to some sort of injection based attack vector.

Comment: This is the query: 

await db.collection('Products').aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Golomax',
        localField: 'barcode',
        foreignField: 'barcode',
        as: 'Golomax'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$Golomax',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Masivos SA',
        localField: 'barcode',
        foreignField: 'barcode',
        as: 'Masivos SA'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$Masivos SA',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $out: 'Output'
}]).toArray();

Comment: And why does that not work?  Why can't you just use the aggregate pipeline?  Why do you have to use `eval`?

Comment: It doesn't work because I have a dynamic number of collections that I am querying from. So I cannot simply execute that exact query since the number of collections (and the names of these collections) are subject to change, so I create the quer string  dynamically.

Comment: I am now using JS eval(query) to execute the query, which works for two collections, but when I have more, I get the following syntax error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: What part of that query is dynamic?  Is it one of the Strings?  What part is changing?

Comment: The collections are dynamic. So 'Golomax' and 'Masivos SA' are subject to change. I get the names from an array of the collection names that I create upon creation of the collections.

Comment: So extract those into variables and change the Strings to variables.

Comment: I got it to work, but I had to create a new async function(). 

var evaluate = async function (queryString) {
  await eval(queryString);
  return true;
}

Then I called evaluate(query) in the main function.

Comment: I couldn't do that because I do not know how many calls to lookup there would be (and as far as I know, there is no way to iterate through a loop in a call to aggregate -- please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `$eval` for this.  It sounds like you want to create a `$lookup` and `$unwind` for each item in an Array.  That is exactly what `map()` is for.  You can create the array of commands separate and then pass it to `aggregate()`:

```js
// Have a list of places
const thingsToUnwind = [
  'Golomax',
  'Masivos SA',
  'Some Other Place',
  'Yet Another Place'
];

const unwindables = thingsToUnwind
  // Create a $lookup and $unwind for each place
  .map(place => {
    return [{
        $lookup: {
          from: place,
          localField: 'barcode',
          foreignField: 'barcode',
          as: place
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: `$${place}`,
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      }
    ];
  })
  // Flatten the array of arrays
  .reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []);

// Add an $output node
unwindables.push({
  $out: 'Output'
});

// Perform the aggregation
await db
  .collection('Products')
  .aggregate(unwindables)
  .toArray();
```

Comment: @JanetLee Sure, don't forget to upvote and accept if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own problem using the Javascript eval() and removing the "await" at the beginning of the string. It executes perfectly now!